# how is possible create database inside existing cluster with Mongo atlas api endpoint?

Tags: mongodb

how is possible create database inside existing cluster with Mongo atlas api?

I'm trying to use `POST /groups/{GROUP-ID}/databaseUsers` but didn't work.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/api/database-users-create-a-user/

Answer (score -1):

The MongoDB Atlas API is for programmatic access to Atlas' management, monitoring, and backup features. API connections are to the Atlas service, not to the underlying MongoDB clusters.

The same problem in https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/226070/mongo-atlas-api-get-databases-and-collections-in-a-cluster

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31746716)